# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Surname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have error although console dispays value of $("#surname").val().
May be script works before form is dynamic building?

```
  $(function () {
    $("#addEmployeForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/values/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                Name: $("#name").val(),
                Surname: $("#surname").val(),
                Age: $("#age").val(),
                Salary: $("#salary").val(),
                PhoneNumber: $("#phoneNumber").val(),
                Department: $("#department:selected").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#resultSpan").html(data[1].Surname)                
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log($("#surname").val());
            }
        });
        console.log("after ajax: " + $("#surname").val());

    });
});
```

Comment: Which line ? You have multiple usage of $("#surname").val().

Comment: Can you be any more specific about the error?

Comment: The only place you're trying to access a `Surname` property is here: `data[1].Surname`, so that's where your issue is.  can you `console.log(data)` in your success function to see what's being returned?

Comment: Unless the returning object from the success call back has the same structure and content as your sending object, your success call back won't work because data[1] is referencing the returning object, not the sending object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting suggests the AJAX call was **successful**, but there is no such object as `data[1]` being referenced in the following code: `$("#resultSpan").html(data[1].Surname)`.  I recommend `console.log(data)` where you're trying to access `data[1]` to see what data is actually being returned from your AJAX call.